# #1265 Data truncated from column 'tfidfglobal'. Whats wrong with my query?

Tags: java, mysql, decimal, tf-idf, truncated

Well, I'm working on text clustering and I have a problem with saving my tf-idf and tfidfglobal value to my database. So, I'm using a query to calculate the tf-idf value of a word. The data type of tf-idf and tfidfglobal column is `Decimal(65,3)`, I thought it was the largest length for the `Decimal` but still have an issue of truncated data.

I have tried to change the data type from `Decimal` to `Text` and it works well, one of a row that has truncated data issue has a tifidf value of 2,606.806.

But when the data type is `Decimal`, it shows a warning of truncated data and the value of tfidf becomes 2.000.

What I need is not a Text data type but a Decimal data type, because I need to do some arithmetic operations with this value. Here is my query:

```
INSERT INTO features (id_komentar, kata, tf, tfglobal, IDF, tfidf, tfidfglobal) 
    SELECT tf.id_komentar, tf.kata, tf.tf, tfglobal.tfglobal, format(idf.idf, 3) AS idf, 
           format(tf*idf, 3) AS tfidf, format(tfglobal*idf, 3) AS tfidfglobal 
    FROM 
        ((SELECT id_komentar, kata, COUNT(kata) AS tf FROM words GROUP BY id_komentar, kata) tf 
    INNER JOIN 
        (SELECT kata, COUNT(kata) AS tfglobal FROM words GROUP BY kata) tfglobal 
        ON tf.kata = tfglobal.kata 
    INNER JOIN 
        (SELECT kata, format(Log(n/df), 3) AS idf FROM 
        (SELECT kata, COUNT(id_komentar) AS df FROM (SELECT DISTINCT kata, id_komentar FROM words) df 
        GROUP BY kata) df, 
        (SELECT COUNT(id) AS n FROM comments) n
        ) idf ON tfglobal.kata = idf.kata
    ) 
    INNER JOIN 
    (SELECT kata, COUNT(id_komentar) as df FROM 
        (SELECT DISTINCT kata, id_komentar FROM words) df GROUP BY kata) df 
    ON idf.kata = df.kata  
    ORDER BY `tf`.`id_komentar` ASC
```

What's wrong with it? I thought the value 2,606.806 isn't bigger than `Decimal(65,3)` but I still have a truncated data issue.

Comment: Try `2606.806` without thousands separator, which might have been confused for decimal separator. And note that 1.2 * 1.2 = 1.44

Comment: Thank you, it works. I remove the thousand separator.